# How do I add a header to urllib2 opener?

Tags: python, http, header, urllib2

```
cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))    
opener.open('http://abc.com')
opener.open('http://google.com')
```

As you can see, I use opener to visit different websites, using a cookie jar. Can I set a header so that each time a website is it, the header is applied?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You can add the headers directly to the `OpenerDirector` object returned by `build_opener`. From the last example in the [urllib2 docs](http://docs.python.org/release/2.6/library/urllib2.html#examples):

> OpenerDirector automatically adds a User-Agent header to every Request. To change this:

```
import urllib2
opener = urllib2.build_opener()
opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]
opener.open('http://www.example.com/')
```

> Also, remember that a few standard headers (Content-Length, Content-Type and Host) are added when the Request is passed to urlopen() (or OpenerDirector.open()).

Comment: @PiotrDobrogost, to be fair, this particular functionality is underdocumented. The [`OpenerDirector`](http://docs.python.org/release/2.6/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.OpenerDirector) class entry is bare; the above information is _very_ easy to miss.

Answer (score 18):

```
headers = {'foo': 'bar',}
req = urllib2.Request(url, None, headers)
resp = urllib2.urlopen(req)
```

or

```
req = urllib2.Request(url)
req.add_header('foo', 'bar')
resp = urllib2.urlopen(req)
```

Comment: `opener` is whole a different object, you can't use `Request` in this case.