# How do I add a user-agent to this Python opener?

Tags: python, url

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I add a header to urllib2 opener?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6259489/how-do-i-add-a-header-to-urllib2-opener)

```
cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
```

How do i add a user agent header to this?

Answer (score 2):

Not a direct answer - as Mateusz is correct for your direct question, but I strongly suggest if you're going to be doing a lot of this you consider the `requests` library at http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/index.html

That way it's as simple as:

```
import requests

r = requests.get('http://whatever.com/', headers={'User-Agent': 'xxxx'})
```

You also get cookies handled for you, basic auth is easier, and it's easy to plug-in OAuth bits - check out the docs, you may find it useful.

Answer (score 1):

```
request = urllib2.Request(your_webpage)
request.add_header('User-Agent', your_user-agent) 
data = opener.open(request).read()
```