# why I can't log in this web with python

Tags: python, authentication, urllib2

This is my python code．I want to log in this website with python, but it can't come true.

```
 import sys, time, os, re
 import urllib, urllib2, cookielib

 loginurl = 'https://auth.dxy.cn/login?null'
 #loginurl = 'https://www.douban.com/accounts/login'

 cookie = cookielib.CookieJar()
 opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cookie))
 urllib2.install_opener(opener)

 params = {
         'username' : 'XXXX',
         'password' : 'XXXX',
         'lt' : '_c573C07C4-AD13-CD25-85E9-CC917AF0433F_k42B35CAA-C2E7-7B2C-A7A1-9FD4E6CBE30F',
         '_eventId' : 'submit'
         }

 req = urllib2.Request(loginurl,urllib.urlencode(params))
 res = urllib2.urlopen(req).read()
 m = re.search(r'\s+(.+?)\s+',str(cookie))
 jsession=re.sub(r'\s+', '', m.group(0))
 #print jsession

 header={'Cookie':jsession}
 #response=opener.open(req).read()
 req1 = urllib2.Request(loginurl,urllib.urlencode(params),header)
 res1 = urllib2.urlopen(req1)
 print res1.geturl()

 response1=opener.open(res1.geturl())
 print response1.read()
```

Comment: Is there an error? What is the result of the print statements?

Comment: no error, the result of the print statements is still the log in webset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ive had similar problems before because of user-agent issues. Try log in normally (via your browser of choice) and take a look at whatever header info is sent. Try mimic that in your script.

If you don't know how to set the headers check this out: [How do I add a header to urllib2 opener?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6259489/how-do-i-add-a-header-to-urllib2-opener)

Comment: please mark this as the correct answer if that's what it is. Otherwise post your answer